# Finding memory leaks in DirectX program

Tags: memory-leaks, directx

Background:
I have a Visual Studio 2013 project, involving DirectX (version 9). The project is an x86 solution. When running it in DirectX debug mode, I can't get rid of all the memory leaks.

Output from Visual Studio debug:

```
Direct3D9: :====> ENTER: DLLMAIN(6417d9a0): Process Detach 0000350c, tid=0000363c
Direct3D9: (INFO) :MemFini!
Direct3D9: (ERROR) :Memory still allocated!  Alloc count = 975
Direct3D9: (ERROR) :Current Process (pid) = 0000350c
<Solution name> has triggered a breakpoint.
The program '[13580] <Solution name>' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

From the above I learned that the program has finished with 975 items still allocated and not destroyed or released. That it has triggered a breakpoint is due the setting in DirectX debug ("Break on emory leak").

So before posting actual code, I tried to use the PIX utility Microsoft ships with DirectX. By capturing the same solution I got the result below, which indicates that every object created, has also been destroyed.

[Screen shot from PIX showing objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO8Lg.png)

So, I am left with a memory leak according to VS2013 but not according to PIX. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Direct3D 9 debugging isn't supported on Windows 8 or later. The debugging runtimes provided in the legacy DirectX SDK really only match Windows 7 RTM. They are a little buggy on Service Pack 1 and with DirectX 11.1 installed.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, the debugging seems to work in other aspects besides this contradicting information.

Comment: Presumably you have Service Pack 1 installed and likely KB 2670838 as well. Really both legacy PIX for Windows and the Direct3D 9 debug layer are 'as is', so it is quite likely to have false reporting bugs in places. See [DirectX 11.1 and Windows 7 Update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/02/26/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update/). VS 2013 installed the Windows 8.1 SDK which provides the correct debug layer for Direct3D 11 when using DirectX 11.1 on Windows 7 SP1.